# javax.ws is not found inside a java servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

This is my imports that can work

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
```

And this is my servlet signature:

```
public class Multipart1 extends HttpServlet {
```

I am using tomcat 8.

I want to use the `MediaType` enum (maybe it is a class i don't remember), and it is in the `javax.ws.rs.core` but the problem is that when i do import, the only thing that starts with `w` under `javax` is `websocket`, I couldn't find `ws`

What am i missing please?

It seems i have to include some maven dependencies, but I thought that it is a javax so it should come all together in the jdk, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in the JDK, you have to import the dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```